# React function enter twice in if condition inside Map function

Tags: reactjs, function, dictionary, if-statement, state

my function handleAddPoint receive data like this:

```
data = {colorid,counter}
```

I call this function from child component called "Qualificatif" who just push data based on a onChange event from a Select input.

Each time i change the value from my select input, the map function inside the function called handleAddPoint go twice in the if condition.

Can you help me ?

Here is the code:

```
export default class Questionnaire extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state ={
            colors:[
                {
                    id:1,
                    color:"yellow",
                    point:0
                },
                {
                    id:2,
                    color:"green",
                    point:0
                },
                {
                    id:3,
                    color:"red",
                    point:0
                },
                {
                    id:4,
                    color:"blue",
                    point:0
                },
            ],
        }

        this.handleAddPoint = this.handleAddPoint.bind(this)
    }

    handleAddPoint = (data) =>{
        console.log("Data questionnaire",data)
        this.setState(state => {
            state.colors.map(color => 
                {if(color.id === data.colorid)
                    color.point += data.counter
                    return color
                })
        })
        console.log("couleurs questionnaire",this.state.colors)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="questionnaire">
                <Qualificatif data={Q1data} handleaddpoint={this.handleAddPoint}/>
                <Qualificatif data={Q2data} handleaddpoint={this.handleAddPoint}/>
                <Classement data={Q3data} handleaddpoint={this.handleAddPoint}/>
                <Result data={this.state.colors}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 things I could find that were wrong with the code is that you mutate state in handleAddPoint an you are trying to log state after setState but setState does not change the state immediately so you won't log the changed state.

Here is a working example, I guess the other components have some breaking problems as well but since they are not posted in your question I just created them from scratch.

```js
const { Component } = React;
const Item = React.memo(function Component({
  data,
  handleaddpoint,
}) {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => handleaddpoint(data)}>
      add {data.color}
    </button>
  );
});
const Result = React.memo(function Result({ data }) {
  return <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2)}</pre>;
});
class Questionnaire extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      colors: [
        {
          id: 1,
          color: 'yellow',
          point: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          color: 'green',
          point: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          color: 'red',
          point: 0,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          color: 'blue',
          point: 0,
        },
      ],
    };
    //handleAddPoint is an arrow function no need to bind
    //  it as arrow functions are automatically bound
    // this.handleAddPoint = this.handleAddPoint.bind(this);
  }

  handleAddPoint = (data) =>
    this.setState((state) => ({
      //you were mutating state.colors[x], you cannot
      //  mutate state
      colors: state.colors.map((color) =>
        color.id === data.id
          ? { ...color, point: color.point + 1 }
          : color
      ),
    }));

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="questionnaire">
        <Item
          data={this.state.colors[0]}
          handleaddpoint={this.handleAddPoint}
        />
        <Item
          data={this.state.colors[1]}
          handleaddpoint={this.handleAddPoint}
        />
        <Item
          data={this.state.colors[2]}
          handleaddpoint={this.handleAddPoint}
        />
        <Result data={this.state.colors} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Questionnaire />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```